# Unsure why group_by function in dplyr is not working

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by

I'm new to R and trying to understand how dplyr works so I can apply it to a dataset that I have. I'm trying to work through this example with the starwars API:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/dplyr.html

I'm trying to group the starwars dataframe by species and sex, and then find the mean of each species and sex. The code is copied from the tutorial:

```
starwars %>%
  group_by(species, sex) %>%
  select(height, mass) %>%
  summarise(
    height = mean(height, na.rm = TRUE),
    mass = mean(mass, na.rm = TRUE)
  )
```

And I should be getting this output:

```
#> Adding missing grouping variables: `species`, `sex`
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'species'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 41 x 4
#> # Groups:   species [38]
#>   species  sex   height  mass
#>   <chr>    <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 Aleena   male      79    15
#> 2 Besalisk male     198   102
#> 3 Cerean   male     198    82
#> 4 Chagrian male     196   NaN
#> # … with 37 more rows
```

But instead I'm getting this:

```
#> Adding missing grouping variables: `species`, `sex`
#>    height     mass
#> 1 174.358 97.31186
```

Could someone help me understand why it's collapsing all species and sex together, and then taking the mean of height and mass, instead of maintaining the separate groups?

Thanks!

Comment: The posted code works for me. What version of `dplyr` are you using? Does the code work if you remove the `select` line from the pipe chain?

Comment: Interesting. I cannot replicate your results. Restart Rstudio and only import "dplyr", maybe you have some conflicts with other packages?

Comment: Looks like you might be loading `library(plyr)` after `dplyr`, which would supercede ("mask") `dplyr'`s functions `arrange, count, desc, failwith, id, mutate, summarise, summarize`. `plyr` is retired/superceded since 2018 so it probably makes sense to replace any usage with `dplyr`, its successor from the same author.

Comment: Following @LMc recommendation, function "select" could be in conflict with other packages (e.g., MASS). You can also write your 3rd row as:  `dplyr::select(height, mass) %>%`